# Eclipse could not resolve string resource error

Tags: android, eclipse

I just created a new android project and prepared the basic structure for it. Eclipse is telling me that it couldn't resolve any strings, even the standard `"hello"` or `"app_name"` strings :O Restarting the IDE didn't help. Any suggestions? A screenshot can be found [here](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/wp5r9)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I noticed that in your project, there is no `values` resource folder. The resource in the folder with the suffix of `-de`,`-en` will be applied when the language on the device is German, UK, but the default folder should not be deleted. Try to add the `values` folder and corresponding `string.xml` to the project.

Comment: So I just need an (almost)empty folder that is never used..?

Comment: No,because that's the default folder, if the language of the user's device is not de,en,or ru,etc,as you pre-defined, the app will know what to do.

Comment: @Huang : I have a values-fa folder that is related to a specific language as you said. It's a project that I downloaded. It has some string values in that folder and they are used form some activities, but when I add a string to this resource folder and use it in my activities or layout, the application cannot resolve it. But if I define that string in the default value folder, application can resolve it! What's the problem?!

Comment: @Behzad The rule is that every string resource should have a "default" version in the xml file in the values folder.  I.e you define a string called name="ab" in the values folder and you defines its Chinese version name="dc" in the values-zh folder, when the local language of the device is not Chinese, "ab" would be used. For your problem, just define that string in values folder and define its specific version in different values-XX folders as you need.

Comment: @Huang Thanks. So if the local language of the device isn't Chinese, the defined value in this folder wouldn't be used ever?

Comment: @Behzad Yes, that's why you need the international locale for specific language.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the strings.xml file under values folder, remove the resource that's causing the problem (in this case "app_name") and write it again - new one.

Answer (score 1):

Try quick saving the strings.xml file after modifying your string resource, or save the entire project File->Save All menu... it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to clean your project

```
Project > Clean
```

If that doesn't work, make sure you don't have a typo or something in your three strings.xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have deleted the default `values folder` in your `res` directory. You need to keep that as well with the other language specific values folders. You need to create `res->Values->strings.xml` and add your string resources to it.