# could not resolve resource android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new in andorid development.
I have created my android first project according to http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

And here is the code that I have as the project was created(no changes are done in code by me)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the screenshot of the Graphical layout
http://imageshack.us/a/img35/5284/android1s.png

So, it looks fine for now, but if I want to change the text `Hello world` to , say, `hello`, so the code's part looks like `android:text="@string/hello"`, I get the error

`NOTE: This project contains resource errors, so aapt did not succeed, which can cause rendering failures. Fix resource problems first.`

and

`Couldn't resolve resource @string/hello`, and the text in graphical layout becomes
`@string/hello`, as it is in this image

http://imageshack.us/a/img826/7735/android2p.png

But I noticed one thing:
If after this error I go to `res/values/strings.xml` and add `String` with name and value `hello`, like

http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/8108/android3s.png

The error disappears and I can see the word `hello` in the graphical layout.

I tried these so far

1. Using `ctrl+shift+s` like it is described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14462434/932473
2. Closing and reopening Eclipse.
3. cleaning, rebulding
4. removing the entire project and creating again.

The `values` folder does exist in `res`.

None of these questions solved my problem

[Eclipse could not resolve string resource error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240995/eclipse-could-not-resolve-string-resource-error)

[Can't Resolve Android Resource Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427890/cant-resolve-android-resource-strings)

**UPDATED**
If I write like this `android:text="hello"`
I get this warning in eclipse 
`Hardcoded string "hello", should use @string resource`,

I do not get it every time I want to use some string like `android:text="@string/hello2"`, I have to first manually specify `hello2` it in `strings.xml` ?

Comment: you shoudl make a entry of the string hello in strings.xml

Comment: that's a lint warning you that you have used harcoded string. yes you need to make a entry in strings.xml for the string you refer. like       <string name="hello2">whateverilike</string>

Comment: ok, Thanks @Raghunandan, and about that warning that I get in eclipse, so what is the right or preferred way, use just `android:text="hello"`, or `android:text="@string/hello"` and specify it in `strings.xml` ?

Comment: the second way is the preferred way. the lint only warns you. its not a error specifying in strings.xml is preferred way

Comment: @Raghunandan, but is not it a little slow ? so that I should manually add `<string name="hello2">whateverilike</string>` in `strings.xml`? is not there any way to make automatically appear necessary things in `strings.xml` as I write smth like `android:text="@string/some_new_message"` in my code ?

Comment: no not possible. its not slow. the difference between hardcoded string and fetching the referred string in strings.xml by android is less than few milliseconds. so as a user you won't notice it at all

Comment: no I did not mean the programming speed, I mean if I write `android:text="@string/some_new_message"`, and the `some_new_message` does not exist in `strings.xml` and in order to my error go away I have to manually go to `strings.xml`, click `Add` and write the variable name there, it takes some time, I meant this :), so if I have a very big project and there are a dozens of variables, so, I have to manually, one by one add them in `strings.xml` ?

Comment: see the edited answer. say you drag and drop a textview into your layout. right on the textview. click edittext. there you can see the pops as shown in the edited answer. you can make a entry to the strings.xml on clicking new string. that's one way or you have to manually goto strings.xml and make a entry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In res/values/strings.xml

```
      <string name="hello">Hello</string>
```

Then refer the string in your textview as

```
      android:text="@string/hello"
```

I guess you do not have something similar to above. Hence you get resource not found exception coz the resource is not defined in strings.xml

```
                 or
```

You can do as below

```
       <string name="hello_world">hello</string> // change the string in strings.xml      
       android:text="@string/hello_world"
```

For the question in the comment

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, also one more question, what is better about using `android:text="@string/hello"`, instead of `android:text="hello"`, I mean, maybe it will be easier to make changes in the future, or maybe it is more dynamic, so why it is the preferred way ?

Comment: suppose you want to use the string in all textviews . then you will have to hardcode everywhere. instead you can make a entry in strings.xml and refer to the same string many times. That's the preferred way. this is exactly why lint warns you about the same.

Comment: I guess I got it, so if I want to change it in all textviews, I will only make a change in `strings.xml` right ?

Comment: yup you are right. you can also use string resources from android framework. Like you want ok button in your button you can android:text="@android:string/ok" this avoids duplicity. instead of using your own ok string you can use the one defined in the framework

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
android:text="hello"
```

the @string bit means its a resource called `hello` in your xml.

So you can also add the resource to your xml if you wish. Its known to be better practice, for internationalization.